# How to check whether java is installed on the computer

Tags: java, runtime

I am trying to install java windows application on client machine.I want to check whether
requried JRE is installed on the machine or not. I want to check it by java program not by cmd command

Comment: Go to command prompt and simply type "java" and press Enter ;)

Comment: this has a problem, if java is installed but not set in path, this might give you misleading results

Comment: "I want to check it by java program" So you don't want to check just that java is installed, but also the correct version? Like from a bootstrap?

Comment: You will be able to see a screen like, [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMToI.png)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

if you are using windows or linux operating system then type in command prompt / terminal

```
java -version
```

If java is correctly installed then you will get something like this

```
java version "1.7.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Side note: *After installation of Java on a windows operating system, the PATH variable is changed to add java.exe so you need to re-open cmd.exe to reload the PATH variable.*

**Edit:**

CD to the path first...

```
cd C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath
java -version
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question - "I want to check it by java program not by cmd command". A good answer to this question is below by A4L (https://stackoverflow.com/a/18888451/100465).

Answer (score 9):

You can do it programmatically by reading the `java` system properties

```
@Test
public void javaVersion() {
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.runtime.version"));
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.home"));
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.vendor"));
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.vendor.url"));
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.class.path"));
}
```

This will output somthing like

```
1.7.0_17
1.7.0_17-b02
C:\workspaces\Oracle\jdk1.7\jre
Oracle Corporation
http://java.oracle.com/
C:\workspaces\Misc\Miscellaneous\bin; ...
```

The first line shows the version number. You can parse it an see whether it fits your minimun required java version or not. You can find a description for the naming convention [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/versioning-naming-139433.html) and more infos [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/jdk-version-number-scheme-1918258.html).

Comment: This is the correct answer if you want to do it using java, like it says in the question.

Answer (score 5):

Open Command Prompt and type in the following command: `java -version`

Upon successful execution, the command will output the version of Java along with Java SE Runtime Environment’s build and Java HotSpot Client VM’s build.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question - "I want to check it by java program not by cmd command"

Comment: @ZachAlberico, Yes, but the question was answered before it was edited by the OP.

Comment: Ah that makes sense - didn't catch that.

Answer (score 4):

**command prompt:**

```
C:\Users\admin>java -version (Press Enter>
java version "1.7.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 3):

Go to this link and wait for a while to load.

http://www.java.com/en/download/testjava.jsp

You will see the below image:
[image]

You can alternatively open command window and type `java -version`

Comment: This solution would only work if you have the Java browser plugin installed and enabled, which really you shouldn't. Some modern browsers don't support or won't allow the Java plugin to run. For instance Google Chrome has no support for Java plugin

Comment: MOST modern browsers do not support the NPAPI anymore. The latest version of firefox that supports Java is Firefox-ESR 51

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question - "I want to check it by java program not by cmd command"

Answer (score 0):

After installing Java, set the path in environmental variables and then open the command prompt and type `java -version`. If installed properly, it'll list the java version, jre version, etc.

You can additionally check by trying the `javac` command too. If it displays some data, you've your java installed with the proper path set, else it'll that `javac` is an invalid command.

Comment: I was about to comment on javac ;)

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question - "I want to check it by java program not by cmd command"

Comment: @ZachAlberico The question was edited after the answer was posted. Is that the reason for your downvote?

Answer (score 0):

Type in the command window

```
java -version
```

If it gives an output everything should be fine. If you want to develop software you might want to set the PATH.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question - "I want to check it by java program not by cmd command"

Answer (score 0):

Check the installation directories (typically `C:\Program Files (x86)` or `C:\Program Files`) for the java folder. If it contains the JRE you have java installed.

Answer (score 0):

type **java -version**  in command prompt, it will give you the installed version of java on your system.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question - "I want to check it by java program not by cmd command"

Answer (score 0):

1)Open the command prompt or terminal based on your OS.

2)Then type `java --version` in the terminal.

3) If java is installed successfullly it will show the respective version .

Comment: This answer was already posted some times. Anything new you want to add?

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question - "I want to check it by java program not by cmd command"

Answer (score 0):

Using Apache Commons-Lang's [`SystemUtils.isJavaVersionAtLeast(JavaVersion)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/SystemUtils.html#isJavaVersionAtLeast(org.apache.commons.lang3.JavaVersion))

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.JavaVersion;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.SystemUtils;

if (SystemUtils.isJavaVersionAtLeast(JavaVersion.JAVA_1_8)
    System.out.println("Java version was 8 or greater!");
```

Answer (score -1):

If java not installed yet. Then program written by java cannot be run to check if java is installed or not.