# Installing Oracle form and got an error. Cannot launch the installer (555)

Tags: oracle, installation

**Oracle form** downloaded at:

[image]
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/forms/downloads/index.html

When I ran the file `setup_fmw_12.2.1.3.0_fr_win64.exe`,
it gave me an error "*Cannot launch the installer (555)*".

---

fmw_12.2.1.3.0_fr_win64_Disk1_2of2   <-- Folder
   setup_fmw_12.2.1.3.0_fr_win64-2.zip

fmw_12.2.1.3.0_fr_win64_Disk1_1of2   <-- Folder
   setup_fmw_12.2.1.3.0_fr_win64.exe

Answer (score 0):

Even though this relates to the installation of a developer tool, most would consider this particular type of question as **generally off topic** for stackoverflow. Your question also contains too little information to determine what the problem really is.

However, let's just mention some obvious things to see if it helps you solve your own problem:

1. Did you **try the setup on another computer** (or a **virtual machine**). This could be a good way to avoid the whole problem rather than spending a lot of time trying to fix it.
2. Did you locate any **log files** for the failed install?

   - A quick look seems to indicate that you can find log files at: `%SystemDrive%\Program Files\Oracle\Inventory\logs` (`%SystemDrive%` is normally `C:\`).
   - Or `%SystemDrive%\Program Files (x86)\Oracle\Inventory\logs` for 32bit installers on 64 bit systems).
   - [**Found in the troubleshoot section here**](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12213/formsandreports/install-fnr/troubleshooting.htm#FRINS247) - *have a look yourself too - **read from the top***.
3. And the most obvious of all: did you contact **Oracle support** or search their **user community** or **knowledge bases**? Somebody will have seen this problem before. Looks like you need to register: https://support.oracle.com/
4. A quick search reveals that the [**Oracle Universal Installer**](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/em.920/a96697/oui.htm) is a **Java based installer**. *Could Java be broken on the box you install on*? (looks like the launcher should install the runtime automatically, but this could fail due to special conditions on the box. **Try on a clean virtual machine**). [How to check whether java is installed on the computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18888220/how-to-check-whether-java-is-installed-on-the-computer/18888250#18888250).
5. Try **disabling your anti-virus** as well before running the setup on the problem box. Some setups even try to access the Internet during installation, and then your **firewall** could be a problem too. I would hate to turn that off though.