# How do you install cx_oracle on a Windows server that does not have an internet connection?

Tags: python, windows-installer, cx-oracle

I have to install oracle_cx on a Windows server. The server is not allowed to have internet access for any reason. I have no problem installing oracle_cx with pip on workstations with internet access. Need a way to install it without internet.

Looked for answers on the web for several hours. None found.

Comment: What happens when you try to install? Does it abort? Do you have a log file? What type of setup is it? MSI / Windows Installer? [This is not that Oracle Universal Installer is it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46323388/installing-oracle-form-and-got-an-error-cannot-launch-the-installer-555) (older answer regarding that tool - look for the log file?).

Answer (score 0):

Download the proper file from [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/cx-Oracle/#files) and then use the command

`python -m pip install "<file_name>"`

Comment: Yes - I have done that. As explained I thought.